# How to wrap all toplevel statements and declarations except imports in jscodeshift?

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I have this AST explorer [snippet](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0104f1edd962e05d33a4a77b10bd8dab/4430088c4f7013e6b3c61194f00296a44e14d01b) which almost lets me do what I want, which is to turn this:

```js
function bar() {return 42;}
var baz = {}
import 'get-outta-here';
```

into

```js
import 'get-outta-here';

function wrap() {
  function bar() {return 42;}
  var baz = {}
}();
```

i.e. wrap all top-level statements and declarations except the `import` ones.  However, my jscodeshift transform is buggy in a way I can't understand.

- I can wrap, and remove the imports, but I can't move them to the top.
- I can move them to the top but not wrap

I suspect my wrapping logic is off: `root.get().value.program.body` sounds hacky.

```js
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  const wrapper = j(j.expressionStatement(
        j.callExpression(
          j.functionExpression(
            j.identifier('foo'), [],
            j.blockStatement(root.get().value.program.body)
          ), []), []));
  
  const nodes = root.find(j.ImportDeclaration).nodes();
  root.find(j.ImportDeclaration).remove();

  // wraps, but doesn't re-add the import at top-level
  return wrapper.toSource();
  
  // fails
  // return wrapper.find(j.Statement).at(0).insertBefore(nodes).toSource();
  
  // moves it to the beginning, but no wrap
  return root.find(j.Statement).at(0).insertBefore(nodes).toSource();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.  Just use `j.program` to put a proper "Program" AST in `wrapper`.

```js
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  const wrapper = j(
    j.program([
      j.expressionStatement(
        j.callExpression(
          j.functionExpression(
            j.identifier("foo"),
            [],
            j.blockStatement(root.get().value.program.body)
          ),
          []
        ),
        []
      )
    ])
  );

  const imports = root.find(j.ImportDeclaration);
  const nodes = imports.nodes();
  imports.remove();
  return wrapper.find(j.Statement).at(0).insertBefore(nodes).toSource();
}
```

Comment: It works! I left the code for the full example at the folder [crguezl/hello-jscodeshift/wraptoplevelstatments](https://github.com/crguezl/hello-jscodeshift/tree/master/wraptoplevelstatments)